# Epics vs Projects vs something else

Tags: scrum, jira, epics

We have just started using JIRA and I'm setting it up now.

We have a huge product and an external team which develops and supports the product.

Our product involves a lot of projects. The development team will be working on several different projects in any given sprint.

How can we set up workflow for this in JIRA?

Should we have all our projects combined as a single project in JIRA?

How can we combine stories from different projects in a single sprint?

Maybe our projects should actually be epics? Or something else?

**UPD**

Sorry for delay. "Project" for us it is some part of our big web-site. For example "Search 2.0" or "Integration with XYZ". Project has deadlines. "Project" can be done. It doesn't have scope and team from start.

Comment: Can you give us more detail about what these "projects" are like? Do you mean project in the sense of a "activity to achieve a goal" or do you mean project as in "code solution".

Comment: Following what rb asked, are the projects expected to be constantly evolving or they won't be related to each other?

Comment: sorry for delay. see upd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want multiple 'projects' to be on the same Scrum-board Sprint, then you can accomplish that by having a board with the JQL filter set to read from multiple JIRA projects (ie. 'project = MultiTestOne OR project = MultiTestTwo ORDER BY Rank ASC'). Boards and projects are set up 1-to-1 by default when you create a project, but there's nothing stopping you from later altering the JQL.

As for Epics: without further information on what exactly you mean by 'project', I can't give an opinion on whether or not they would make sense via Epics. If it works and everyone on your team is okay with it, though, then I don't see why not. At their heart, all Epics in JIRA are is simply a way to group Issues.

Without further information, I can't possibly decide for you which of the two (or a perhaps a third) options is the best for your situation. You need to discuss with the Team to see what makes the most sense.

As a side note, you stated that

> The development team will be working on several different projects in any given sprint.

What is the reason for this? Are the projects highly related? Are they just so small that doing only a single project per sprint is infeasible? If the Development Team is working on a multitude of unrelated tasks during a sprint, you may want to consider an approach other than Scrum, such as Kanban.

Comment: Why does devteam work with many projects? Because they are big and external for us. We prepare stories from different projects for our big devteam. Maybe it isn't most effective approach. But it is so.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQL to show projects in a single board, 
then you can plan sprints with issues from multiple projects,

but as the team/roles is same(i am assuming as it seems that the projects are branches of a large product), use the same workflow for all projects, (not essential but easier on reporting)

Also your projects do not need to be just Epics in this scenario, what if the smaller projects evolve into large products, the hassle will be enough to commit suicide.

also take a look
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/64932/combining-multiple-projects-into-1-sprint

Keep Calm and JQL it.